# Storing Variables in Array

Tags: php, csv, oop

I'm trying to create a CSV converter which will take a CSV, parse the data, and output it into a standard format.

This requires created somewhat of a data map for each type of CSV that will be converted.

What I want to do is store each of the row mappings into a respective class for that CSV and then use it within the converters class when using a foreach loop.

```
class CsvImporter {
    public function exportCSV()
    {
        $headers = ['store','websites','attribute_set','type','category_ids','sku','has_options','name','image','small_image','thumbnail','cost','upc','price','special_price','weight','msrp','status','visibility','tax_class_id','description','short_description','qty','is_in_stock','product_name','store_id','product_type_id','manufacturer','pla_category','pla_stock','condition','mpn'];

        $data = $this->parseCSV();

        if ($this->feed = 'feed1'){
            //return feed1 mapping
        } else{
            //return feed2 mapping
        }

        foreach($data as $row) {
            $importData['store']        =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['website']      =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['attribute_set'] =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['type']         =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['category_ids'] =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['sku']          =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['has_options']  =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['name']         =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['image']        =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['small_image']  =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['thumbnail']    =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['cost']         =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['upc']          =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['price']        =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['special_price'] =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['weight']       =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['msrp']         =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['status']       =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['visibility']   =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['tax_class_id'] =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['description']  =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['short_description'] =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['qty']          =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['is_in_stock']  =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['product_name'] =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['store_id']     =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['product_type_id']  =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['manufacturer'] =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['pla_category'] =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['pla_stock']    =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['condition']    =  //return values from class mapping here
            $importData['mpn']          =  //return values from class mapping here
        }

        fclose($handle);
    }
}

class Feed1{
    const feed = 'feed1';
    const db = '';  //initialize db connection

    private static $mapping =[
        $this->store,
        $this->website,
        'Default',
        'simple',
        '',
         $row['4'],
        '0',
         $row[8] . " " . $row[15],
        '',
        '';
        '',
        $row[9],
        $row[6],
        ($row[9] / 0.85) + $row[14],
        '',
        $row[14],
        '',
        'Enabled',
        '"Catalog, Search"',
        'Taxable Goods',
        $row[16],
        '',
        $row[1],
        ($row[1] > 0) ? 1 : 0,
        $row[15],
        '',
        'simple',
        $row[8],
        '285',
        ($row[1] > 0) ? 'in stock' : 'out of stock',
        'new',
        $row[4],
    ]
}
class Feed2{
    const feed = 'feed2';
    const db = ''; //initialize db connection

    private static $mapping =[
        $this->store,
        $this->website,
        'Default',
        'simple',
        '',
         $row['0'],
        '0',
         $row[5] . " " . $row[1],
        '',
        '';
        '',
        $row[6],
        $row[7],
        $row[8],
        '',
        $row[9],
        '',
        'Enabled',
        '"Catalog, Search"',
        'Taxable Goods',
        $row[12],
        '',
        $row[11],
        ($row[10] > 0) ? 1 : 0,
        $row[3],
        '',
        'simple',
        $row[4],
        '285',
        ($row[17] > 0) ? 'in stock' : 'out of stock',
        'new',
        $row[15]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a constructor for your Feedx classes that takes the row as an argument, otherwise they won't know what $row is.

You also need to create methods for accessing the data held by $mapping.

Maybe a better way would be to create methods that return whatever field you're trying to get? E.g.:

```
public function getStore() {
    return $this->mapping['store'];
}
```

Which you could then call like this:

```
$feedObject->getStore();
```

But since it's an object, maybe instead of having a single attribute that holds all the data, maybe each could be it's own attribute. Then in your constructor you could do this:

```
function __construct($row) {
    $this->store = 'Default'
    ...
    $this->cost = $row[9];
    ... etc.
```

Which would be clearer for anyone needing to read that code (including your future self, and us SO folks).

But if you're doing that, then you don't really need two classes, do you? They're both doing the same thing, with the same attributes and methods. All you need is a way to separate the differences. Maybe an init method?

```
public function __construct($type, $row) {
    $this->type = $type;
    $this->row  = $row;
}

public function init() {
    $this->store = 'Default';
    ... etc.
    $this->cost = ($this->type == 'feed1') ? $this->row[9] : $this->row[7];
    $this->price = ($this->type == 'feed1') ? $this->row[11] : $this->row[15];
    .... etc.
```

... or maybe each method just does that on the fly, without using class attributes:

```
function getPrice() {
    return ($this->type == 'feed1') ? $this->row[9] : $this->row[10];
}
```